# Will Texas Instruments' flash memory reader fully support an SDHC flash card?

Tags: windows-xp, sd-card, readyboost, sdhc

I bought my laptop in 2006, and I have Windows XP Home on it. On my Texas Instruments multimedia reader says that it supports SD, but it does not say anything about [SDHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC). I heard some say to buy an SDHC memory reader and some say that there is a chance that my SD reader will support SDHC.

I researched some and found **[a post on CNET](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6122_102-272217.html)** that says to download a Windows XP SDHC support hotfix and the newest driver for the Texas Instruments media reader. He and others claim this to be working.

Will these updates make the SD media reader fully support SDHC flash cards in terms of speed, features etc. and will I get all the benefits of the SDHC flash card to use it for [ReadyBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the SHDC standard wasn't set until June 2006 I doubt that your laptop shipped able to read SDHC. It may be that a firmware update for the reader can make it read SDHC cards and that thread does suggest that your reader may be one of those.

You've got nothing to lose, so why not try it?

---

What it will give you is higher card size support. I certainly wouldn't expect a firmware upgrade to result in a major performance improvement in any device.

Comment: Money. If i buy SDHC card and my card reader will read it at the speed of SD card then i have done nothing.